# shopping basket using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there is an easy way to create a grid of info and checkbox for each row of that using Tkinter.

I'm trying this:

```
def make_info_table(page, info):
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(3):
            text = tk.Text(page, width=23, height=2)
            text.grid(row=2 + x, column=y)
            text.insert(tk.END, info[x][y])

EducationalBookPage = tk.Frame(root, bg='#87CEFA')
pageLabel = tk.Label(EducationalBookPage, text="Educational books", bg='#87CEFA')
pageLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

backButton = tk.Button(EducationalBookPage, text='Back', command=lambda: change_page(EducationalBookPage, mainPage))
backButton.grid(row=1, column=2)

educationalBookName = ['Educational book' + str(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
educationalBookPrice = [i * 10000 for i in range(1, 5)]
educationalBookPublication = [' ' + str(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
info = [('publisher', 'price', 'name')] + list(zip(educationalBookPublication, educationalBookPrice, educationalBookName ))

make_info_table(EducationalBookPage, info)
```

is there any better way to create a selection grid?

Comment: `for`-loop is standard method to do it. And it can be the most flexible.

Comment: I would send all data to function and inside function I would use the same `for`-loops to get x, y and to get values from lists.

Comment: There is widget [TreeView](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) or modules like [Pandatable](https://dmnfarrell.github.io/pandastable/) but sometimes it can be simpler to use only `for`-loop like in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is widget [TreeView](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) or modules like [Pandatable](https://dmnfarrell.github.io/pandastable/) but sometimes it can be simpler to use only `for`-loop like in your code.

But I would use `enumerate()` to work with any number of data.
And to use `item` instead of `info[x][y]`.

```
def make_info_table(page, data):
    for y, row in enumerate(data):
        for x, item in enumerate(row):
            text = tk.Text(page, width=23, height=2)
            text.grid(row=2+y, column=x)
            text.insert(tk.END, item)
```

I also replaced variables `x`,`y` because `row` is like `y` on plot, and `column` is like `x` on plot. Eventually I would use more readable values `r` (like `row`) for `y` and `c` (like `column`) for `x`

```
def make_info_table(page, data):
    for r, row in enumerate(data):
        for c, item in enumerate(row):
            text = tk.Text(page, width=23, height=2)
            text.grid(row=2+r, column=c)
            text.insert(tk.END, item)
```

---

Full working code so everyone can copy and test it.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def make_info_table(page, data):
    
    for r, row in enumerate(data):
        for c, item in enumerate(row):
            text = tk.Text(page, width=23, height=2)
            text.grid(row=2+r, column=c)
            text.insert(tk.END, item)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

page = tk.Frame(root, bg='#87CEFA')
page.pack()

label = tk.Label(page, text="Educational books", bg='#87CEFA')
label.grid(row=0, column=1)

button = tk.Button(page, text='Back', command=lambda: change_page(page, mainPage))
button.grid(row=1, column=2)

ITEMS = 15

data = ( [('publisher', 'price', 'name')] + 
          [(f'Educational book {i}', i*10000, str(i)) for i in range(1, ITEMS+1)] )

make_info_table(page, data)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]